# Django admin save and display data only for the logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my django admin project i have to save and then display data for different user, i would that when i save automatically field user take the loged in user value and when i re logged in i can see only the data saved for my user only.
I have this kind of models.py:

```
class TheLinks(models.Model):
    lk_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lk_name

class UserComLinks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User")
    l_id = models.ForeignKey(TheLinks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Portal")
    l_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.l_id)
```

now if i run my django admin i see this form:

[image]

well, first i would to hide the username field and make my model save in automatic this data  using the current logged in user then i would that when the user logged in can see only hos data.
I try to manage admin.py in this kind of fashion:

admin.py

```
class UserComLinksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('l_id',  'l_link')

def changeform_view(self, request, obj_id, form_url, extra_context=None):

        try:
            l_mod = UserComLink.objects.latest('id')
        except Exception:
            l_mod = None

        extra_context = {
            'lmod': l_mod,
        }
        return super(UserComLinksAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, obj_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

but nothing change.

Can someone pleas help me about?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can *exclude* the `user` field from the admin form and set the value of current user before saving:

```
class UserComLinksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('l_id',  'l_link')
    exclude = ('user',)

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        obj = super().save_form(request, form, change)
        if not change:
            obj.user = request.user
        return obj
```